# Accessing a pointer to a vector c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector

Im having trouble accessing the following vector. Im new to vectors so this is probably a small syntactical thing i've done wrong. here is the code....

```
void spellCheck(vector<string> * fileRead)
{   
    string fileName = "/usr/dict/words";
    vector<string> dict;        // Stores file

    // Open the words text file
    cout << "Opening: "<< fileName << " for read" << endl;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(fileName.c_str());

    if(!fin.good())
    {
        cerr << "Error: File could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    // Reads all words into a vector
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        string temp;
        fin >> temp;
        dict.push_back(temp);
    }

    cout << "Making comparisons…" << endl;
    // Go through each word in vector
    for(int i=0; i < fileRead->size(); i++)
    {
        bool found = false;

        // Go through and match it with a dictionary word
        for(int j= 0; j < dict.size(); j++)
        {   
            if(WordCmp(fileRead[i]->c_str(), dict[j].c_str()) != 0)
            {
                found = true;   
            }
        }

        if(found == false)
        {
            cout << fileRead[i] << "Not found" << endl; 
        }
    }
}

int WordCmp(char* Word1, char* Word2)
{
    if(!strcmp(Word1,Word2))
        return 0;
    if(Word1[0] != Word2[0])
        return 100;
    float AveWordLen = ((strlen(Word1) + strlen(Word2)) / 2.0);

    return int(NumUniqueChars(Word1,Word2)/ AveWordLen * 100);
}
```

The error is in the lines

```
if(WordCmp(fileRead[i]->c_str(), dict[j].c_str()) != 0)
```

and

```
cout << fileRead[i] << "Not found" << endl;
```

the problem seems to be, because its in the form of a pointer the current syntax im using to access it is made invalid.

Comment: Why aren't you passing a reference rather than a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unary * to get a vector& from a vector*:

```
cout << (*fileRead)[i] << "Not found" << endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `[]` on a pointer to a vector will not call `std::vector::operator[]`.  To call `std::vector::operator[]` as you want, you must have a vector, not a vector pointer.

The syntax to access the n-th element of a vector with a pointer to the vector would be: `(*fileRead)[n].c_str()`.

However, you should just pass a reference to the vector:

`void spellCheck(vector<string>& fileRead)`

Then it's just:

`fileRead[n].c_str()`

Comment: I assume you meant `vector<string> & fileRead`?

Comment: @cHao Yes.  Thanks!  Copied and pasted the method signature, but forgot to change it >.<.

Answer (score 1):

Two options to access:

- `(*fileRead)[i]`
- `fileRead->operator[](i)`

One option to improve the method

- pass by reference

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass fileRead by reference like this:

```
void spellCheck(vector<string> & fileRead)
```

Or add a dereferece when you use it like this:

```
if(WordCmp( (*fileRead)[i]->c_str(), dict[j].c_str()) != 0)
```